# Why is JavaScript's bind() not working here as I expect it?

Tags: javascript, this, bind

```
class Test {
    DISPATCH_TABLE = {
        "Outer Method": this.outerMethod
    }
    innerMethod() {
        console.log("success");
    }
    outerMethod() {
        console.log(this);
        this.innerMethod();
    }
    dispatch(method_name) {
        this.DISPATCH_TABLE[method_name]()
    }
    constructor() {
        this.outerMethod = this.outerMethod.bind(this)
    }
}
t = new Test()
t.dispatch("Outer Method")
```

This logs the dispatch table itself and then prints the error, "this.innerMethod is not a function". I understand why *this* would be bound to the dispatch table **without** the bind() call in the constructor, but I thought that including that call was supposed to force *this* to refer to the class in any calls to the bound method.

I'm not blaming JavaScript or bind() for my expectation. I just don't know why my expectation is wrong.

I could just use a switch statement instead of a dispatch table, but I'd prefer to use a dispatch table if I can.

Comment: You're defining `DISPATCH_TABLE` before the bind happens.

Comment: That's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have a better time using arrow functions, which are always correctly this-bound.

I took the liberty of changing your dispatch table to map "verbose names" of function to internal method names, too.

```
class Test {
  DISPATCH_TABLE = {
    "Outer Method": "outerMethod",
  };
  innerMethod = () => {
    console.log("success");
  };
  outerMethod = () => {
    console.log(this);
    this.innerMethod();
  };
  dispatch(method_name) {
    const meth = this[this.DISPATCH_TABLE[method_name]];
    if (!meth) throw new Error(`no such method ${meth}`);
    return meth();
  }
}
t = new Test();
t.dispatch("Outer Method");
```